# How to set upload directory? PHP, jQuery File Upload

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, upload

I am using the [jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html) to handle uploading images.

At the moment uploaded files are being store inside `/themes/mytheme/assets/plugins/file-upload/server/php/files/upload/test' which is controlled by the below code in`UploadHandler.php` …

```
'upload_dir' => dirname('$this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME'')).'/uploads/test/',
'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/uploads/files/',
```

I want to store uploads inside `mywebsite.com/uploads/test/` but whatever I change the code to it doesnt let me get out of the folder `/server/php/` … I've tried the below methods:

1)

```
'upload_dir' => '/uploads/test/',
'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/uploads/files/',
```

2)

```
'upload_dir' => dirname('www.mywebsite.com')./uploads/test/',
'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/uploads/files/',
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Upload path cannot be based on site url but has to be based on the real path of the directory on the server.

```
'upload_path' => '/full/path/to/www/upload/files/'
```

or something like that...

it depends on your server type

use

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

to get the physical path to the web root, e.g. /var/www/example.com/httpdocs